# Facebook graph API get last page posts

Tags: facebook

it is my first time with the Graph Facebook/Meta api,and I do not understand if the APP needs to be created in the same Facebook account where the app want to access? Or can I create an app with my developer account to get the last posts of a page from another person (for example a client)? I followed the official Doc, but still not understand this part. Thanks

Comment: Other users can grant your app permission to access their pages.